# EF Core: How to use foreign key in a PostgreSQL array

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core, foreign-keys

I have a PostgreSQL database with following tables:

```sql
create table tbl1(
    id serial primary key,
    ...
)

create table tbl2(
    id serial primary key,
    tbl1_ids int[]
)
```

`tbl2.tbl1_ids` is a reference to the `tbl1.id` (I prefer not to declare it as foreign key, but I can do that if it solves my problem).
It works fine, and it's significantly more space efficient than using the traditional N-M relation.
However, I don't know how to declare an [EF Core navigation property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#single-navigation-property-1).
I'd expect something like this to work.

```cs
class Tbl2 {
    // these two work fine
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int[] Tbl1Ids { get; set; }

    // I'd like to do this, so I can use it in queries
    public Tbl1[] Tbl1s { get; set; }
}
```

EF apparently only recognizes navigation properties if the foreign key property ends with `Id`, but it also seems to expect that it has type `int`, not `int[]`. I'd expect I'll need to do some Fluent API configuration for this, but I could not figure this out yet.

Comment: Not sure why you think an array of ids can be equal to a single id. Make it a FK and move on.

Comment: It works in SQL just fine. I really don't want to make it a classic M:N relationship, since this table is pretty big in practice (~70GB) and this makes it significantly more efficient (since all the ids are inlined in one row, not spread across multiple pages). My current alternative is to just write in SQL and move on :|

Comment: You are working in a SQL database, so sticking with SQL is the better choice. As to table size you should see if [Partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html) would work for you?

Comment: I hope I won't need to use partitioning , but ~100s GB is managable just fine by one node. I'm using raw SQL for lot of querying anyway, but I was hoping that EF could simplify some "select 'all columns' JOIN the_related_tables where id=?" queries

Comment: You can not declare foreign keys against array elements. If you want proper foreign keys, you will have to normalize your data model